# url response not able to map in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and trying to create a ecommerce website. For the navigation and category items, I have used a endpoint url.

http://149.129.128.3:3737/search/resources/store/1/categoryview/@top?depthAndLimit=-1,-1,-1,-1

and the screenshot of response is given below

[image]

The problem which I'm facing is that when I click on the categories like Apparel, Electronics, upto the first level of category, I'm able to render it.

[image]

But under that subsection, there is another category, which I'm not able to render(E.g under Girls there is shoes, pants etc) and the code is given below

topNavigation.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import SubMenu from './subMenu';



class Navigation extends Component {

  state = {
    mainCategory: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3030/topCategory')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data.express);
        this.setState({
          mainCategory: res.data.express.catalogGroupView
        })
      })
  }



  render() {

    const { mainCategory } = this.state;
    return mainCategory.map(navList => {
      return (

        <ul className="header">
          <li key={navList.uniqueID}> 
          <a className="dropbtn ">

          {navList.name}

          <ul className="dropdown-content">
          <SubMenu below={navList.catalogGroupView}/> 
          </ul>

          </a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      )

    })

  }


}

export default Navigation;
```

subMenu.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SubListMenu from './subListMenu';


class SubMenu extends Component {
    render() {
        const {below} = this.props;
        return below.map(sub => {

            return (
                <div>
                     <li key={sub.uniqueID}> <a>{sub.name}</a></li>
                     <SubListMenu subBelow={this.props}/>
                </div>


            )
        })

    }

}

export default SubMenu;
```

subListMenu.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SubListMenu extends Component {

        render() {
            const {subBelow} = this.props;
            return subBelow.map(sub => {

                return (

                        <li key={sub.uniqueID}> <a>{sub.name}</a></li>

                )
            })

        }

    }

    export default SubListMenu;
```

Can someone please help me on this. I'm not able to figure it out. I don't know where my code is getting wrong. Or if somebody could atleast give an insight how to proceed further.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line: 
 
`<SubListMenu subBelow={this.props}/>`

to this:

`<SubListMenu {...this.props}/>`

or to this

`<SubListMenu subBelow={this.props.below}/>`

You are passing the whole `props` object to `subBelow`, so you are trying to map through an object, but `Object.prototype.map` is not a function.

Comment: I have tried to make the changes in the code as suggested by you. But you can see in the json response and in the link which I have provided that under the girl section there are categories like shoes, pants which stil is not rendered. Can you please help me.

Comment: If I undestand corrrectly, you have made the changes, the js error disappeared but the items are still not rendered?

Comment: Yes exactly, the error has gone but the items are not rendered